# JDK was not found on the computer for NetBeans 6.5

Tags: netbeans, java, netbeans6.5

I got the following message when I open the NetBeans. I have got the JDK installed, and set the bin directory in the environment. What I could do next to avoid this problem? Btw, I am using Windows 7 64 bit.

[image]

Comment: For me, downloading the 64-bit version of Java solved the problem (32 didn't help)

Comment: Note that ```C:\Programs\java\jdk-XX.X.X\bin``` is not the JAVA_HOME, instead omit ```bin``` and it is ```C:\Programs\java\jdk-XX.X.X\```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I use the following steps to solve the problem:

First, Make sure

```
“Run this program in compatibality mode for: Windows XP (Service Pack 3)” and “Run this program as an administrator” are ENABLED.
```

Run in Command Prompt

```
C:\Users\{yourusernamehere}\Documents\Downloads\netbeans-6.5-ml-windows.exe –-javahome "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_18"
```

Comment: I would suggest running `java -version` in the command line to make sure you are using the 64-bit version.

Answer (score 40):

Do the following steps to resolve the problem

1. Ensure that the JDK is already installed.
2. If the installer is on a CD, Copy the EXE file for the Netbeans 6.5.1 installer onto your hard disk.
3. Note the location of the installer.
4. Open a Command Prompt running as administrator:
   Go to Start button > All Programs > Accessories
   Right click Command Prompt
   Select Run as administrator
5. In the Command Prompt use the cd command to change to the directory containing the installer.
6. Execute the following command to extract the contents of the installer: [Note: You might need to change the name of the installer to match the one you have.]

   **netbeans-6.5.1-ml-java-windows.exe  --extract**
7. Execute the following command to manually execute the installer:

   **java  -jar  bundle.jar**

You will see rapid scrolling output in the Command Prompt window for a few moments, then the installer window will appear to begin the installation process.

Comment: now that's a solution worked for JDK 12.0.1 and netbeans-8.2-javaee-windows

Comment: Perfect solution, I am also getting this problem. as per above-mentioned instruction, I got the solution

Comment: Awesome, but... how do I uninstall it after installing it like this?

Answer (score 7):

I would first double-check that you installed the JDK, rather than just the JRE. It's easy to grab the wrong one and not even realize it. Then I'd make sure that your JAVA_HOME environment variable is pointing to your JDK install directory, NOT the bin directory. You may want to add the bin directory to the PATH environment variable, but Netbeans is more likely looking at the JAVA_HOME environment variable.

Answer (score 7):

I was facing the same problem, not it works fine.

1. just open cmd
2. cd to the directory where your netbeans setup file is located.
3. in cmd, write the name of the entire setup file and write --javahome "address of jdk"
4. hit enter, it will surely solve your problem

for example, if the setup file is:  netbeans8.02.exe

and path of JDK is C:/program files/java/jdk9.01

then run the command,

netbeans8.02.exe --javahome "C:/program files/java/jdk9.01"

and hit enter! :-)

Answer (score 3):

go to cmd and enter the following command:

> C:\Users{usernamehere}\Documents\Downloads\netbeans-{version}.exe
>   –-javahome "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk{version}"

before it make sure you have properly set the environment variable.
If it is not works than check compatibility of program or
reinstall jdk appropriately and set environment again and do as above command.

Answer (score 2):

You have to either provide `JAVA_HOME` environment variable which points to the `JDK` location or as it says, you can run the installer from the command line passing `JDK` address through its `-javahome` argument like this:

```
C:> <NetBeans_Installer_Name> -javahome <JDK-PATH>
```

You must also make sure that your installed JDK is the Windows 64-bit version of the program. This is the download link for JDK6U37: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u37-b06/jdk-6u37-windows-x64.exe

Answer (score 2):

**For netbeans 8.2**
1. First run command as administrator.
2. set path to you downloads folder using **cd 'location to the downloads folder'**
3. extract using **netbeans-8.2-windows.exe --extract** command
4. run **java -jar bundle.jar**
5. Done :)

Comment: That is just a shortened version of [Bhuvan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27647491/1951524) from 2014.

Answer (score 1):

When this type of problem occurs simply delete previous path setting and add new path in Environment variable.

new path name JAVA_HOME
path "Your computer path" without \bin

and also edit path variable with \bin path.

netbeans will working fine whatever the version is.either jdk 9 or upper version.

Comment: You have to elaborate on your answer or it is just a comment not to be in answer section.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem, and solve by this way:

1. Open CMD
2. Go to file netbeans.exe
3. Press Shift Key + Right Click and copy as path
   [Copy as path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaTBf.png)
4. Paste on CMD look like C:\Users\unnamed>"C:\Users\unnamed\Downloads\Programs\netbeans-8.2-windows.exe"
5. Write --javahome do same point 2 on JDK folder
6. Write on cmd look like C:\Users\unnamed>"C:\Users\unnamed\Downloads\Programs\netbeans-8.2-windows.exe" --javahome "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4"
7. Enter. Enjoy it.

Answer (score 0):

From the **commnand prompt** execute the following two commands:

`netbeans-6.5.1-windows.exe –extract`         **//two dashes before extract**

```
java -jar bundle.jar
```

The first one extracts the installer from the exe while the other executes the installer.

according to this link:http://fuzz-box.blogspot.com/2011/05/netbeans-65-jdk-not-found.html

Answer (score 0):

Set JAVA_HOME and PATH,
Open Command line with admin rights,
Run in command line >>netbeans-6.5.1-ml-windows.exe --extract,
Run in command line >>java -jar bundle.jar

Answer (score 0):

This is still an issue when installing NetBeans 8.0. To install it, first confirm that JDK is installed correctly. On my machine, it was located in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11

Then, I was able to install NetBeans 8.0 by restarting my computer in Safe Mode With Networking. When running the NetBeans exe installation file in Safe Mode With Networking, it will prompt you to confirm the location of the Java JDK directory.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to net beans folder where you have installed it.
2. Right click uninstall icon and select properties
3. select the compatibility tab and click the check box "Run this program in compatibility mode"
4. Apply changes
5. From command prompt, run the following command : >uninstall.exe -javahome C:\YOUR_JRE_LOCATION

Answer (score 0):

write in the command prompt

```
C:>netbeans8.2-windows.exe -javahome"path of your jdk" -jrehome"path of your jre"
```

netbeans version may be different so type that name i.e. if you have `netbeans 6.5`, then write `netbeans6.5` instead of `8.2`.

Answer (score 0):

You just simply needs to add JAVA_HOME environment variable and provide the complete path of the latest JDK folder on your computer.

Re launch the installer and it would work.

Answer (score 0):

I got this Error today while installing latest Java 10.0.1 ( downloaded JDK in official oracle website) and also downloaded NetBeans version 8.2.

My JDK installation went as smooth as Cake.

But the problem is in Netbeans installation. When I tried to install Netbeans, the error message showed was: "JDK was not installed on your system. Try using Javahome installer argument". But nothing helped me.

Solution:

- Download JRE alone from their website.
- Move your NetBeans installer to local drives other than c.
- Install JRE by clicking the exe file.
- Set JAVA_HOME, PATH in environment variables.
- Install NetBeans now.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem while installing the NetBeans
but I did  the installation part properly
simply you have do is 
1-> GO and download the JRE file of java
link -> https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html

2-> After installing the JRE kindly go to directory where you have install the JRE 
3-> And copy all the file of from the JRE folder 
4-> And paste in the jdk folder but
5-> while copying the file make sure you replace-and-copy the file while any prompt pop out

6-> Then open the command prompt(cmd) and simply type 
7->netbeans-8.2-windows.exe --javahome "path-of-your-jdk-file"

Answer (score 0):

For Netbeans 9.0

1)open netbeans.conf file using notepad inside etc folder

2)Search "netbeans_jdkhome" line and uncomment it by removing '#' from start

3)locate your jdk and replace file path

For example

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I have got the JDK installed

You haven't specified the version. I think it is not 6 nor 5.

JDK 6 was the latest version at time of NetBeans 6.0 - 6.9 are developed. For that reason, **They require JDK 6 (or JDK 5)** and do not run on JDK 7 or later.

[Download JDK 6](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-ee-sdk-6u3-jdk-6u29-downloads-523388.html)

[Download latest version of NetBeans](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/index.html)

Answer (score -1):

What I have found, the correct way of doing it is:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\netbeans-8.0.2-windows.exe" --javahome "C:\Program  Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51"

1. at first, the setup of NetBeans must be saved on your hard disk
2. go to the place where your setup is, click properties and copy the path.
3. Add two back slashes in it and put it in double quotes like so: 
   "C:\Program Files (x86)\netbeans-8.0.2-windows.exe"
4. then go to the folder where your jdk is, click properties, copy the path, put 
   double back slashes where necessary and then put it in double quotes: 
   "C:\Program  Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51"
5. then just follow the format of the first link given and you'll install it

Note: run this link in the command prompt

Comment: The question is about NetBeans 6.5 and JDK 1.5 or 1.6. It is also five years old.