# NetBeans installer Not locating Java properly

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to install the NetBeans "all" package, and, I'm pretty sure I already have Java SE Development Kit installed, however, it's not locating it properly, it comes with an error.

```
Java SE Development Kit (JDK) was not found on this computer
```

So I ran the CMD and typed:

```
netbeans-7.1.3-windows.exe --javahome "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25"
```

As I checked, I was in the right directory (E:\Mark\Downloads) where the setup file of netbeans is supposed to be. After pressing ENTER, it did locate JDK, however it would not locate JRE and came up with this error.

```
Java Runtime Environment (JRE) was not found
There is no JRE at the specified location C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25
```

So I tried installing the JDK+NetBeans Bundle by Oracle [x86 (32-bit) for Windows (I'm running a 32-bit Windows XP SP3 so it should have worked)] but it says that it's not compatible with my current platform. I also tried --jdkhome but it didn't seem to work at all. Please, this has been going on for two days.

Comment: Did you try passing the JRE directory path instead of the JDK?

Comment: check whether jdk path is properly set.

Comment: Hmm... you must be right, since, I tried doing that, and it doesn't locate the JRE at all even at the jre folder, should I redownload? I mean, it must have been in the folder, but it's not.

Comment: UPDATE: I set the path on the environment variable right, but then, NetBeans installer still won't locate JRE properly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JDK was not found on the computer for netbeans 6.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079472/jdk-was-not-found-on-the-computer-for-netbeans-6-5)

Comment: Here is the solution to this problem. Take a look

http://stackoverflow.com/a/27647491/1521346

Comment: Found the solution here. It worked for me.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/27647491/1521346

Answer (score 16):

The exe seems to be a wrapper for a jar installer. you can extract the jar installer and run that.

```
 .\netbeans-8.2-javase-windows.exe --extract netbeans
 java -jar netbeans\bundle.jar
```

'netbeans' in the above is the name of the folder you want the bundle.jar extracted to it could be anything.

I had a similar error message and couldn't get it to work with the --javahome option but running the jar worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

I've fought with this problem, and I use a no-hassle solution for Linux.

Instead of installing Netbeans from https://netbeans.org/, download it from Oracle packaged with JDK.

Here is the [current link.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7-netbeans-download-432126.html)  It changes all the time though so just google for `netbeans jdk` in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I also was facing this problem,then i found this jre is not installed
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html
i installed it,and then opened netbeans.exe ,It ran successfully.

Comment: You shouldn't post links, since one day the content may be taken down

Answer (score 1):

The working solution for me was right click on `netbeans_installer.exe` and choose "Run as administrator". I hope, it will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

To be compatible with netbeans version 8, java jdk version 8 should be used. I solved this problem by uninstalling my Java SE Development Kit 13 and installing version 8

Answer (score 0):

Just check if JDK is properly installed at C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25.

In case your JDK installation should be compromised, try uninstalling it and re-installing jdk1.7.0_25 at the same location.

Comment: I reinstalled it, and yet, still didn't work, and, I quite noticed that it might be the jre that's causing the problem. I'm not sure, though... where can I get more information?

Comment: @MarkPaulino Since jre is bundled inside jdk, Netbeans should be able to find it as long as you install jdk at the right location. From the error information you provided, I suspect 1)you actually installed the right version jdk, i.e., jdk1.7.0_25, but jre inside the jdk directory has been tampered or 2)you didn't install the same version as jdk1.7.0_25

Answer (score 0):

Dont't try to locate jdk just enter the path for jre(Java runtime environment) which is installed in the same folder if you installed jdk properly.

```
netbeans-8.2-windows.exe --javahome "C:\Program Files\Java\jre-9.0.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the NetBeans and the JDK together - **bundled version**. Shouldn't have any problems in installation then

http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/widget/jdk_netbeans.jsp

Answer (score 0):

For me, the main problem was that I installed **incompatible JDK version**, and the error said "The specified jdk folder does not contain jdk". 
As said above, the easiest solution is to install the bundle, or install a compatible version of JDK.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I assumed without thinking about it that JDK 11 should work.  Then I read this from the Netbeans installation instructions:

> The Java SE Development Kit (JDK) 8 is required to install NetBeans
>   IDE.

After downloading JDK 8 and using it to install Netbeans, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error after using cmd to install Netbeans 8.2 with JDK 13.0.2, but everything was ok after I installed JRE 8 from the official website. I didn't even have to use cmd after installing JRE.

Answer (score 0):

For Netbeans 12 the parameter was actually --jdkhome instead.

Create a shortcut to netbeans64.exe then right-click go into properties and add the following into the "target" field (with a space in front of the --).

`--jdkhome "C:\Program Files\OpenJDK\openjdk-11.0.7_10"`

(Google Adopt OpenJDK if you need the jdk)