# Java SE Development Kit not found on this computer

Tags: java, netbeans, java-8, java-9

I had netbeans 8.1 installed on my PC (windows 8.1) with JDK version 8. I uninstalled netbeans 8.1 and then installed netbeans 8.2. After installation I ran it and everything worked fine.

After installing netbeans 8.1, I uninstalled JDK 8 and then installed JDK 9.

After installing JDK 9, when I tried to run NetBeans again, it gave me error that

> Java SE Development Kit not found on this computer

[image]

I looked it up on the internet and came to know that cause of this error was that when NetBeans 8.2 was installed with JDK version 8, NetBeans was configured to use JDK 8. So when JDK 9 was installed, NetBeans couldn't find the JDK 8 which it was configured to use by default and hence this error was thrown.

I then uninstalled NetBeans again and then when I tried to run its setup again, it gave me the same error. Now I can't even run the NetBeans setup.

Can someone suggest a solution to this problem?

**PS.** I have already added JDK 9 to environment path variable.

Comment: What's the JAVA_HOME set on your machine? Also I believe to setup Java8 is required still for Netbeans which can further be configured to use JDK9.

Comment: I'd assume you need to edit [netbeans.conf](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqNetbeansConf) and change the `netbeans_jdkhome` variable?

Comment: @KarlReid i have uninstalled netbeans as mentioned in my question, so there's no `netbeans.conf` file on my PC now.

Comment: @nullpointer how can i check which `JAVA_HOME` is set on my PC ? I have `intelliJ Idea` installed too on my PC and it works absolutely fine with `JDK 9`.

Comment: i am using windows 8.1

Comment: open up a command prompt and type `java -version`, what happens?  Also, `echo %JAVA_HOME%` should point at where you have jdk installed.

Comment: @Taylor information about java version is displayed. It is configured correctly

Comment: Did you try solutions suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079472/jdk-was-not-found-on-the-computer-for-netbeans-6-5 ?

Comment: Did you really install a JDK and not a JRE? Can you post a `javac -version`?

Comment: @RC.i have JRE installed too. It was installed with JDK 9

Comment: @nullpointer i can't find the  setting to set the JAVA_HOME variable. I have included JDK's `bin` folder's path in environment variables. Is that called  setting `JAVA_HOME` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some searching i have come to know that for `netbeans 8.2`, you need `JDK 8` because `JDK 8` is required to use `JavaFX 8` features in NetBeans IDE 8.2.

After installing `JDK 8`, Problem was fixed.