# How do I uninstall Netbeans 8.2 ide previously installed with jar file?

Tags: java, netbeans, installation, uninstallation

I followed the answer given here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27647491/5904193 to install Netbeans ide 8.2 with jdk 10.0.2 on windows 10 64 bits OS.

After installation, I found that the jdk was generally incompatible with the ide. So I finally got the latest Netbeans version 9.1 from Apache.

This works with my jdk so I decided to clean things up by uninstalling Netbeans 8.2. Attempting to uninstall directly with the uninstall executable fails with the same error as the installer. That is it requests jdk 8 or higher (I have only jdk 10 installed).

I then tried using the jar file trick by extracting the Uninstaller and executing the jar file with Java. Things happened (lots of output in the console screen and uninstall actually completed) but all the program files remain, I can still see the program in Programs and Features and I could even start the app using the desktop shortcut that was not even touched by the uninstall.

I suspect I could uninstall it normally if I installed jdk 8. But, I mean, there has to be a way to uninstall it without jdk 8 after being able to install without that jdk. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> "But, I mean, there has to be a way to uninstall it without jdk 8
>   after being able to install without that jdk."

There is no reason that should be true since you did not did not meet [the "required software" standard for NetBeans 8.2](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/82/relnotes.html#req_sw), which states "**Java SE 8 is required to install and run NetBeans IDE 8.2**", nor did you follow the standard installation process.

So you "installed" NetBeans 8.2, but not successfully. Since it wasn't installed properly it's not surprising that the uninstall process is failing.

> After installation, I found that the jdk was generally incompatible
>   with the ide.

That's because:

- You didn't install NetBeans properly.
- Regardless of that, NetBeans 8.2 does not support the use of any JDK > 8.

> I suspect I could uninstall it normally if I installed jdk 8.

Perhaps, and unfortunately I think that is what you need to try. However, since you chose not to follow the normal NetBeans 8.2 installation process don't be too surprised if you still have problems.

Comment: Thanks for the rundown. But it's not like I did or chose to do something illegal or similar. I was just trying to stay on the bleeding edge. The installer suggested jdk 8 OR any subsequent jdk versions. I am not the first to be surprised that only jdk 8 worked as expected. I just wanted to install the most recent version of everything. I think that's normal enough.

Comment: @SeyiShoboyejo If you are implying that the NetBeans installer should have flagged the absence of JDK 8 as an error and terminated your install process, I agree completely. That is clearly a bug in the installer. But since the NetBeans documentation clearly states that JDK 8 is required, I think it's also fair to say that what you were doing was "illegal". The conflict between what the NetBeans 8.2 documentation requires, and what its installer allows is unfortunate, but it explains why you have problems.

Comment: Okay. Thanks again @skomisa. I absolutely don't imply anything against Netbeans or installer. I am just looking for a way to keep my system free of software I don't use. Since I will be using 9.1, no point keeping 8.2 around...