# JDK was not found on the computer for netbeans 8.2

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8.2

I got the following message when opening NetBeans that JDK has not been found on this computer. I have got the JDK installed, and set the bin directory in the environment.  Btw, I am using Windows 10 Pro 64 bit.

I have tried this in the command prompt.

```
C:\Users\admin\Downloads>netbeans-8.2-windows.exe --javahome "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk-10.0.2"
```

But then I get this message.

```
It's only the launcher stub.
OS: x64
```

Does someone know what I can do about this?
Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK NetBeans 8.2 is not compatible with Java 9 or higher. You may want to install Java 8.

Comment: Oh this was the problem my bad, thanks man.

Comment: You can run Java 9 and higher with [NetBeans 9](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb90/nb90.html) which was released last week. NetBeans 9 can be installed and run concurrently with NetBeans 8.2; the two releases do not impact each other at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JDK was not found on the computer for NetBeans 6.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079472/jdk-was-not-found-on-the-computer-for-netbeans-6-5)

Comment: @Anees Given the cause and solution is different, I'm not sure that is an appropriate duplicate.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Sorry I don't understand what you are saying. Can you clarify it? Are you referring to the  comment or the answer I have posted?

Comment: @Anees I'm responding to your proposed duplicate. If it had been a response to your answer, I would have posted my comment on your answer.

Comment: Of course that is how you should do it. But your comment "Given the cause and solution is different"  is still confusing me. What solution? You mean the accepted answer in the post I have mentioned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java 8 is still the standard for now. Uninstall java 10 and install this and reset your env vars.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Answer (score 0):

Your computer is 64bit. so your jdk should be in Program Files not Program Files(x86)

```
C:\Users\admin\Downloads>netbeans-8.2-windows.exe -javahome "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

JDK 8 was the latest version at time of NetBeans 8.2 is developed. For that reason, **JDK 8 is required for installing and running all NetBeans Bundles of version 8.0 - 8.02**. They do not run on JDK 9 or later.

[Download JDK 8](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

[Download latest version of NetBeans](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/index.html)