# Netbeans installer issue with jdk 11

Tags: netbeans-8

I downloaded and installed jdk 11 and am now trying to install netbeans 8.2. But i get an error which states "JAVA SE was not found on this computer.Make sure JDK is properly installed and run installer again. You can specify valid JDK location using --javahome installer argument."

I created a JAVA_HOME variable and set the value to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin" and set the same value for PATH variable as well. 
How do i fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JDK was not found on the computer for NetBeans 6.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079472/jdk-was-not-found-on-the-computer-for-netbeans-6-5)

Answer (score 5):

You face a couple of issues:

- NetBeans 8.2 requires JDK 8, and it will not work with any version of Java > 8.
- NetBeans does not yet support JDK 11, though the release of a new version which does (NetBeans 10) is imminent.

The easiest approach would be to remove JDK 11 (unless you need it for other reasons apart from NetBeans), install Java 8 then reinstall NetBeans 8.2. It used to be possible to [download NetBeans 8.2 bundled with Java 8](https://netbeans.org/downloads/), but if you try that now Oracle will just redirect you to the Apache NetBeans 9.0 web site.

There is a newer release of NetBeans than 8.2, [Apache NetBeans 9.0](http://netbeans.apache.org/download/index.html). While it supports Java 9 and Java 10, it also does not support Java 11.

**Updated to reflect that NetBeans 10 was released on December 27, 2018:**

<s>If you really want to use Java 11 with NetBeans you can [download the latest Jenkins build of the beta version of NetBeans 10](https://builds.apache.org/job/incubator-netbeans-linux/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/nbbuild/) at your own risk.</s>

If you want to use Java 11 with NetBeans then [download NetBeans 10.0](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/index.html). The download is a zip file and it works on all platforms.

Answer (score 4):

Find netbeans.conf file in *C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.1 RC\etc*.

In that atlas you'll find the `netbeans_jdkhome`.  Set it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the JDK to use by installing from the command line.  So install a JDK 8 (e.g. Azul Zulu Open JDK 8) and then launch the netbeans installer:

```
netbeans-8.2-javaee-windows.exe --javahome "c:\Program Files\Zulu\zulu-8"
```

Once the installation starts, you will be asked which JDK to use for the IDE; make sure to choose your JDK 8 instead of the JDK 11.  I have used this to install NetBeans 8.2RC successfully on Windows 10.