# Netbeans installer does not find JRE but it is installed

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I am trying to install Netbeans but it gives me this error:

The is no JRE at the location C:\Program Files\Java\jdk11.0.2

I have tried specifying --javahome argument to the installer but still nothing and it is installed as you can see in the snippet attached.

[image: Snippet]

Thanks!!

Comment: NetBeans 8.0 does not work with Java 11, you need to download a Java 8 JDK if you want to use that outdated and unsupported NetBeans version. If you need (want to) work with Java 11, you have to use [NetBeans 10](http://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb100/nb100.html)

Comment: (Somewhat) Possible duplicate of [Netbeans installer issue with jdk 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53690482/netbeans-installer-issue-with-jdk-11)

Comment: [java --version] execute the command to confirm which java your system is using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netbeans 8 does only support java 8, better upgrade to Netbeans 10 which works with   Java 11.

Comment: NetBeans 10 absolutely supports Java 11