# Netbeans 8.2 stuck at "Turning on modules" and couldn't launch on Win 10-64bit

Tags: netbeans-8

I have installed netbeans 8.2 and jdk8.
But when i tried to launch, netbeans couldn't pass through "turning on modules", and then automatically crashed without any message dialog.
I tried some solution but none of them worked.
this is my message.log file. Please help me
Thanks for reading!
[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-j-Hbt5D4diDAo0GvITf6qC8ixMNnZXC/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: NetBeans 8 does not work with JDK 12: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53690482/netbeans-installer-issue-with-jdk-11

Comment: But I installed jdk8 and still got that bug :((

Comment: But line 5 of your log states:   "Java; VM; Vendor        = 12.0.1; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 12.0.1+12; Oracle Corporation". So therefore you are using JDK 12. You can change it in [netbeans]/etc/netbeans.conf