# Java SE Development Kit (JDK) was not found by NetBeans 8.2 Installer

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I got this error message when trying to install NetBeans 8.2 in Windows 10 64-bit.

```
Java SE Development Kit (JDK) was not found on this computer
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YALZ8.png]

I installed the JDK, and set the bin directory in the environment.

Comment: Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48671780/7837080). Can you try this? I think this might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem when I first tried to install Netbeans 8.2. I had JDK 11 installed and I tried everything but was not successful. The problem was with Netbeans 8.2 as it does not support JDK above 9. So I installed JDK 8 and it solved the problem for me. You should try this.